# Using text from Google translate

Tags: android, internationalization, usability

This is regarding android application.

As per my analysis, the translation from Google translate is not perfect.

Will it be ok show non-english users a dialog with the following content:

> This application has been translated by using Google Translate and
>   hence could have translation issues. If you see translation problems
>   in your language, please switch to English locale on your device. If
>   possible, help us in fixing language translation problems noticed by
>   you

This question is from the perspective to quality and usability of app by non-english speakers who have set the locale as non-english on their android device.

Comment: You may get better-quality answers on the [user experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to find somebody that can translate it into proper English.
Expensive: [Supertext](http://www.supertext.ch)
Cheap: [MyGengo](http://www.mygengo.com)

But even the cheapest MyGengo translations are normally better than Google. If you app is something professional, I would invest into a real professional translation. Otherwise your usability goes down the drain.